# WordPress - Empty array from SELECT query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have this query in my wordpress plugin. I need to check the database to get a value and compare it, but the sql seems not returning any result.

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'order_codes';   
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE order_code = '$order_code'");

$order_signature = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

I've done a `var_dump($order_signature);` but the resulting array will be always empty.
Is there something wrong in the statement?

Comment: If you actually get an empty _array_, then nothing was technically wrong with your query, it simply did not find any records matching your WHERE criteria.

Comment: @CBroe I've jsut truncated the table and inserted new value, now seems working fine, but it's a strange issue because I had some data into the table that I've called into the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the use of the **$order_code** variable in the query. The **$wpdb->prepare()** method is used to prevent SQL injection by properly escaping input variables, but it seems that in this case, the variable is not being passed correctly.

Try to use this i hope problem will be solve:

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'order_codes';
$order_code = 'your_order_code_value';
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE order_code = %s", $order_code);

$order_signature = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

*By passing the variable correctly to the $wpdb->prepare() method, the query should return the expected results.*